# PHP detect link text in html containing string and wrap some characters around it

Tags: php, function, replace, hyperlink

In a string which contains HTML code I want to detect linktexts and wrap ##this character## around it.

For example.

```
//beginning of string
$string = '
This is random <b>html code</b> which at some point can contain <a href="page.php">a link</a> or even <a href="page2.php" class="link">multiple links</a>.
<br>
But it also contains other <i>random</i> html tags.
';
//end of string
```

The string above would echo html rendered like this:

================================================

This is random **html code** which at some point can contain [a link](https://www.google.com) or even [multiple links](https://www.bing.com).

But it also contains other *random* html tags.

================================================

But what I NEED it to look like is this:

================================================

This is random **html code** which at some point can contain [##a link##](https://www.google.com) or even [##multiple links##](https://www.bing.com).

But it also contains other *random* html tags.

================================================

Since href and class of the < a > tag may vary, I think the best way would be to have a function which looks for the < / a > closing tag and selects everything before it to the last charachter of the opening tag, which is >

So the function should get for example this as input...

```
This is <a href="page.php">a new linktext</a>
```

...then detect this...

```
>a new linktext</a>
```

...and replace it with...

```
>##a new linktext##</a>
```

...and return the entire thing...

```
This is <a href="page.php">##a new linktext##</a>
```

But of course every other working approach is also welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you need to use [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to parse your HTML string and process only anchor tags. You can modify their innerHTML and save them at the end to get a modified HTML with your desired output.

```
<?php 

$html_string = 'This is random <b>html code</b> which at some point can contain <a href="page.php">a link</a> or even <a href="page2.php" class="link">multiple links</a>.
<br>But it also contains other <i>random</i> html tags.';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html_string);

foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName("a") as $each_node){
    $each_node->textContent = "##".$each_node->textContent."##";
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

**Update:**

- To get only the elements inside the body, you can pass it as a subset to the document as mentioned in the [saveHTML](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php) method.
- As discussed in the comments, to avoid `htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity` which occurs because `DOMDocument` confuses this with `&` to represent an HTML entity and expecting a `;` to complete the entity, we replace all `&` with `&amp;` to avoid the confusion and retain them at the end.
- **Note that** we can't use `htmlspecialchars()` as it won't be a HTML document for parsing anymore.

**Code:**

```
$html_string = '<a href="db_test_or_live.website.com/df.php?p=##pending_code&a=##amount&c=##currency">##db_test_or_live.website.com/df.php?p=##pending_code&a=##amount&c=##currency</a>';

$html_string = str_replace("&","&amp;",$html_string);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html_string);

foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName("a") as $each_node){
    $each_node->textContent = "##".$each_node->textContent."##";
}

$html_modified = $dom->saveHTML($dom->getElementsByTagName("body")->item(0));
$html_modified = str_replace(["<body>","</body>"],["",""],$html_modified);
$html_modified = str_replace("&amp;","&",$html_modified);

echo $html_modified;
```

Comment: This echoes a complete html document with doctype and body tags. Is there a way to avoid that and only return the string?

Comment: @DanielM Updated my answer.

Comment: Working great in general. There is only one issue that it's not working for special links I use. See, I have to use these links containing pseudo variables. Here is an example:

<a href="##db_test_or_live.website.com/df.php?p=##pending_code&a=##amount&c=##currency">##db_test_or_live.website.com/df.php?p=##pending_code&a=##amount&c=##currency</a>

When a string contains such a link, I get a bunch of warnings like:
"Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity, line: 22 in..."

Comment: btw, you can also use **linktext** as wrappers instead of ##linktext## in case it somehow interfears with my special links mentioned above.

Comment: Sorry, the website rendered the comment confusing. What I meant was you can also use * as the wrapping character instead of #, if that helps.

Comment: @DanielM You can use `*` or `#` for wrapping. That's up to you. You said about `#` in your post.

Comment: I understand. But please see my longer comment. The link style I mention there is my link BEFORE the function takes action. And for some reason when I have such a link in that mentioned format, your function still works actually, but it gives me these Warnings: Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity, line: 13 in....... on line....

Comment: @DanielM Can I ask how did you get that link? The error arises because of the fact that PHP's DOM Parser expects html entity expression after `&` and hence expects a semi-colon, which is `&amp;`. How did you get to this HTML string though?

Comment: I use these weird links cause they contain pseudo variables which I replace later on in the code with the actual values. Everything with ## will be replaced. The reason why I don't use normal PHP variables is that this string is stored in a DB and I needed a way to replace certain parts in the string/link afterwards. But the & character is only between the GET parameters of the link, which is quite common for links. So is it only the & character which makes problems here in your opinion? But a link like for instance **href="page.php?article=4&page=2"** is pretty common, isn't it?

Comment: @DanielM yes, it is quite common to have `&` in the URL but I was bit concerned about it's occurrence after the URL fragment and in the innerHTML. Regardless, DOMDocument sees it as an HTML entity expecting a `;` to end the entity representation. Anyway, I have updated my code.

Comment: Working great. But is there a specific reason why you removed <p> again from the replacement/removable process? This version gave me an unwanted p tag around the string. I solved it by changing the second to last str_replace line to **$html_modified = str_replace(["<body>","</body>","<p>","</p>"],["","","",""],$html_modified);** I hope that is alright and doesn't cause any side effects (?)

Comment: Oh ok, now I notice that it's making sense. You probably wanted to leave possible p tags inside the string. That's reasonable. So is there a way to remove only the very first <p> and the very last </p> ? Maybe even with character removal. Like removing 3 from the beginning and 4 from the end. Is that a reasonable approach? Thanks.

Comment: @DanielM Yes, I left `<p>` tags because it is quite possible that your HTML string is well structured and has been wrapped inside a `<p>` tag already. So, removing them would be data loss.

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution using preg_replace :

```
$data =  '
         This is random <b>html code</b> which at some point can contain <a 
         href="page.php">a link</a> or even <a href="page2.php" 
         class="link">multiple links</a>.
         <br>But it also contains other <i>random</i> html tags.';
    $pattern ="/(>)([a-z ]*)(<\/a>)/i";
    $replacement = '${1}##${2}##${3}';
    echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $data);
```

The Regex will try to find any pattern link and try to prefix it with ## and postfix with ## .

the output:

```
This is random <b>html code</b> which at some point can contain <a href="page.php">##a link##</a> or even <a href="page2.php" class="link">##multiple links##</a>.
<br>
But it also contains other <i>random</i> html tags.
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: This is really good. Though the other answer fitted better to the additional conditions which ocured.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace string by using:

```
str_replace(">", ">####", $part)
str_replace("</a>", "####</a>", $part)
```

but to detect the part of code which has link in it you can split the code and then join it back after you changed the parts of the code

Comment: this is not a performante solution , the string is totaly dynamic